# Scroll a webview in Robotium?

Tags: android, webview, robotium

How to automatically scroll a WebView down to bottom in Robotium?

We use a WebView to disaply EULA by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found that clicking on the view, then pressing the Down key some set number of times can do what you want.  So something like:

```
solo.clickOnView(getActivity().findViewById(R.id.your_eula_webview_id));
for (int i=0;i<20;i++) {
    solo.sendKey(Solo.DOWN);
}
```

If that doesn't work, try finding something that does using the keyboard on the emulator, and then do the same with Robotium.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using the [scrollDown](http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/com/jayway/android/robotium/robotium-solo/1.5.0/robotium-solo-1.5.0-javadoc.jar!/com/jayway/android/robotium/solo/Solo.html#scrollDown%28%29) function?

Comment: it acts on the screen not any specific view

Answer (score 0):

First answer is work, but it's not flexible

I think you can override the methond

```
clickOnWebElement(By by, int match, boolean scroll){}
```

write

```
solo.sendkey(Solo.DOWN);
```

into it